# IOS7 style blur UICollectionViewCell's view on tap

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to blur the UICollectionViewCell on tap. What I have tried is get a screenshot of the cell tapped and blur the screenshot. Use the blurred screenshot as the background and hide all labels.

The behavior I have been noticing is

1. Tap Cell 1 : Cell 1 disappears
2. Tap Cell 2 : Sort of blurred but I can make out that the wrong cell's content has been blurred
3. Tap Cell 3 : Blurred a bit more
4. Tap Cell 4 : A lot of blur

The issue I think is :

1. The wrong cell content is getting blurred,
2. Blured screenshot is being reused when another cell is blurred hence the increase in blur.

Then I edited the code to set the background to the original unblurred screenshot

1. Tap Cell 1 : Cell 1 disappears
2. Tap Cell 2 : Cell 1's Screenshot appears
3. Tap Cell 3 : Cell 2's screenshot appears

and so on

Here is the code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 //Code to get data from database and add to labels

  if(![[modelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.overviewView.bounds.size, NO, cell.overviewView.window.screen.scale);
      [cell.overviewView drawViewHierarchyInRect:cell.overviewView.frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];
      UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

      snapshotImage = [snapshotImage applyLightEffect];

      cell.overviewView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:snapshotImage];
      cell.overviewView.alpha = 1;

      cell.descLabel.alpha = 0;
      cell.dayLabel.alpha = 0;
      cell.weatherImage.alpha = 0;
      cell.tempLabel.alpha = 0;
  }


  NSLog(@"Cell :%d condition : %@", indexPath.row, weather.desc );
  return cell;
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  WeekCell *cell = (WeekCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSLog(@"%@", cell.descLabel.text);
  if([[modelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
     [modelArray setObject:@"0" atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];
  }else{
    [modelArray setObject:@"1" atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];
  }

  NSLog(@"sequence : %@", modelArray);
  [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

}
```

Comment: what you need can you share a image?

Comment: @Bhaskar added an image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just posting the sample code that u can try,

in the custom `UICollectionViewCell` i named it as `CustomCollectionVIewCell` and its nib file something look like below

[image]

in the above image u can see that `View-backgroundVIew` which contains image view to hold blurred image and `View-ForeGround` is a view which holds normal image and 2 labels one with green and black texts, these 2 labels are added t collection view cell not t any other views.

cell Hierarchy is like below image

[image]

in the code connect all these as outlets in the cell,
`CustomCollectionVIewCell.h`

```
  @interface CustomCollectionVIewCell : UICollectionViewCell

  @property (nonatomic, assign) id<CellFooterDelegate> myCustomdelegate;//define a delegate
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *backGroundView;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blurImageVIew;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *forGroundView;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageView; 
  //..other objects

  @end
```

in `CustomCollectionVIewCell.m` put this

```
//just frame adjustment
- (void)awakeFromNib
 {
    self.backGroundView.frame  = self.contentView.bounds;
    self.blurImageVIew.frame = self.backGroundView.bounds;

    self.forGroundView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    self.cellImageView.frame = self.forGroundView.bounds;
 }
```

and in the controller

```
  -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    CustomCollectionVIewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myCustomdelegate = self;
    cell.cellImageView.image = [dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
 }
```

after selecting the cell u can put a blurred image like below

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

   CustomCollectionVIewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionVIewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.cellImageView.bounds.size);
   [cell.forGroundView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   //   self.blurrImage = [image applyTintEffectWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:25.0f/255.0f green:77.0f/255.0f blue:108.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f ]];
   cell.forGroundView.alpha = 0.0f;
   cell.blurImageVIew.image = [image applyLightEffect];
 }
```

after deselection just change the alpha of the foreground view

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    CustomCollectionVIewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionVIewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.blurImageVIew.image = nil;
    cell.forGroundView.alpha = 1.0f;
 }
```

out will be like below

[image]

hope this helps u .. :)